# Converting Unicoded text to readable text in Python

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, nltk

I have Unicode text as follows

```
(S (NP (N \u0db6\u0dbd\u0dbd\u0dcf)) (VP (V \u0db6\u0dbb\u0dc0\u0dcf)))
```

How do I change this to a readable format by converting the codes '\u0___' in to the relevant readable characters. I'm using python version 2.7

I obtained that output by following code segment in NLTK (3.0) where tree is a **nltk.tree.Tree**

```
for tree in treelist1:
    print unicode(str(tree))
```

I need something like **print(TreePrettyPrinter(tree).text())** where it gives unicode compatible output as I wanted, but with a tree layout that I don't want. Is there a method in NLTK to get such a readable text like output too?

---

Same issue have with the output from

```
for rule in grammar1.productions():
    print(rule.unicode_repr())
```

where grammar1 is **nltk.grammar.CFG**

Output is as follows.

```
VP -> V
VP -> NP V
N -> '\u0db6\u0dbd\u0dca\u0dbd\u0dcf'
N -> '\u0db8\u0dd2\u0db1\u0dd2\u0dc3\u0dcf'
N -> '\u0db8\u0dda\u0dc3\u0dba'
```

Final results are perfectly fine. I only have issues with the representation of the output

Comment: Did you try printing the value contained in the field itself?

Comment: The Windows console is notoriously bad at handling Unicode strings, you may be better creating some sort of interface or file you can output to, rather than lots of explicit encoding/decoding

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams gives the same output for field itself. ex: print(tree) and print(grammar1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solutions are there in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793973/easiest-way-to-remove-unicode-representations-from-a-string-in-python-3). Also works for Python 2.7

Nothing to do with NLTK. Simple solution is just **decode** the output text with **'unicode_escape'**

```
print(str(tree).decode('unicode_escape'))
```

and

```
print(rule.unicode_repr().decode('unicode_escape'))
```

For NTLK kind of solution for print the tree of type **nltk.tree.Tree** as a bracketed text, use the following

```
print(tree.pformat())
```

Comment: a simpler solution is to avoid invoking `unicode_repr` or `str`. `'unicode_escape'` masks the bugs upstream.