# How do I remove \uXXXX from a list of strings?

Tags: python, regex, string, unicode, python-unicode

I want to remove all words that begin with \u. I believe these are unicode '\uXXXX'.

The original string:

```
"RT  \u2066als \u2066@WBHoekstra\u2069 zijn poot maar stijf houdt in de Italiaanse kwestie. Leest Mattheus 25, 2-13 '"
```

Desired output:

```
"RT @WBHoekstra zijn poot maar stijf houdt in de Italiaanse kwestie. Leest Mattheus 25, 2-13 '"
```

I tried using regex like so:

```
re.sub('\u\w+','',item )
```

But I get the following error:

```
"SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape"
```

Comment: You can't match `\u\w+` as there are no such patterns in your string, that is `RT  ⁦als ⁦@WBHoekstra⁩ zijn poot maar stijf houdt in de Italiaanse kwestie. Leest Mattheus 25, 2-13 '`, see https://rextester.com/MDMRR93300. If you need to remove these chars, just use `item=item.replace('\u2066','').replace('\u2069','')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easiest way to remove unicode representations from a string in python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793973/easiest-way-to-remove-unicode-representations-from-a-string-in-python-3)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using `.encode('ascii', 'ignore')`

```
"RT  \u2066als \u2066@WBHoekstra\u2069 zijn poot maar stijf houdt in de Italiaanse kwestie. Leest Mattheus 25, 2-13 '".encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

output

```
 b"RT  als @WBHoekstra zijn poot maar stijf houdt in de Italiaanse kwestie. Leest Mattheus 25, 2-13 '"
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. But, is there a possibility to remove that 'b' at the beginning of the string ? I am preprocessing some tweets and I cannot have that 'b' in there. I just tried removing it using a regex but it does not work.